# Routing of vanity URLs within .NET Core without redirect

Tags: c#, .net-core, routes

Within .NET Core 2, I would like to route a "vanity" URL like [www.domain.com/harveyrelief](http://www.domain.com/harveyrelief) to [www.domain.com/donation/1326](http://www.domain.com/donation/1326) which is serviced by the "donation" controller and "index" action within our website. The list of vanity URLs is maintained within our content management system with new ones being added weekly/monthly.

I could certainly pick these up from a wildcarded route and/or error controller and redirect to the donation controller/action. However, I want to maintain the original vanity URL entered by the donor.

With .NET Core's new architecture, pipeline, etc. is it possible to turn around and redirect processing of a URL within the pipeline and/or custom router without issuing a redirect to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the URL Rewriting Middleware: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Thanks for the info.    I'll take a look at the documentation and code up some test cases.    These vanity URLs come and go as marketing needs change and I would like to avoid website restarts every time they add/remove one.    Setting up fixed routes and/or rewrite rules for the middleware (i.e. pipeline??) seems to imply that a website restart would be required.  

If I could figure out how to provide some sort of route repository/provider for the middleware and set that up at startup and feed it from a db during operation would be great.